# How to setup StorageNotification on GKE with Config Connector

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-config-connector

I'm using the [Config Connector example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector/tree/master/resources/storagenotification) for the StorageNotification but I keep getting the following error (take from `kubectl describe`)

> storagenotification-controller  Update call failed: error applying desired state: project: required field is not set

I have followed the [Setting Config Connector's default namespace](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/setting-default-namespace) but no joy. The StorageNotification API spec doesn't have a field for "project". I thought it just had to be in the right namespace?

All the other resources seem to setup OK. Just the notification is not working. Here is my complete yaml

```
# Bucket Starts the chain of events
apiVersion: storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: StorageBucket
metadata:
  labels:
    app: something-processing
  name: example-something
  namespace: ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}
---
# Pub/Sub topic that bucket events will publish to
apiVersion: pubsub.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: PubSubTopic
metadata:
  name: my-pubsub-topic  
  labels:
    app: something-processing
  namespace: ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}
---
# Publisher IAM permissions
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-pubsub-topic-iam
  namespace: ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}
  labels:
    app: something-processing
spec:
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: pubsub.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: PubSubTopic
    name: my-pubsub-topic
  bindings:
    - role: roles/pubsub.publisher
      members:
        - serviceAccount:service-${GCP_PROJECT_ID}@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com  
---
# Trigger that connects the bucket to the pubsub topic
apiVersion: storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: StorageNotification
metadata:
  name: storage-notification
  namespace: ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}
  project: ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}
  labels:
    app: something-processing
spec:
  bucketRef:
    name: something
  payloadFormat: JSON_API_V1
  topicRef:
    name: my-pubsub-topic
  eventTypes:
    - "OBJECT_FINALIZE"
---
# subscription that gets events from the topic and PUSHes them 
# to the K8s Ingress endpoint
apiVersion: pubsub.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: PubSubSubscription
metadata:
  name: pubsub-subscription-topic
  namespace: ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}
  labels:
    app: something-processing
spec:
  pushConfig:
    # This should match the Ingress path
    pushEndpoint: https://example.zone/some-ingress-end-point/
  topicRef:
    name: my-pubsub-topic
```

Note: I'm using `envsubt` to replace the `${GCP_PROJECT_ID}` with the project ID ;)

Comment: I've tried check your configuration at my test cluster and it works for me without any error. So, at first I've installed Config Connector following documentation https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall using GCP Identity. Then, I replaced  `namespace` in your .yaml with `cnrm-system` and `project` with my project-id. After that, I was able successfully deploy your config. Please try to follow my steps or update your question with step by step instruction how to recreate your issue.

Comment: Thanks @serhii-rohoza so you mean you now have `metadata.namespace: cnrm-system` or `metadata.cnrm-system: PROJECT_ID`; and `metadata.project-id: PROJECT_ID` or just that you replaced its value with your project's ID?

Comment: As you can find at https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall one of the steps is `kubectl create namespace cnrm-system` and as result I have a namespace `cnrm-system`, which I decided to use in your config. Try to follow installation guide.

Comment: OK, so I have followed the guide and now I get the error: `pubsubtopic-controller  Update call failed: error applying desired state: Error creating Topic: googleapi: Error 403: User not authorized to perform this action.` I tried `kubectl --namespace=cnrm-system delete secret gcp-key` and then `kubectl delete pod --namespace=cnrm-system delete pod cnrm-controller-manager-0` but it just repeats the error? I think i was using the recommended "Workload Identity" approach before...?

Comment: Can you try again with `GCP Identity` as it described at https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall ? I haven't noticed that `Workload Identity` was recommended there, it's only an option as I can see.

Comment: I can post my steps with output here like answer if it'll be useful for you.

Comment: @serhii-rohoza yes please

Comment: Did you try to follow steps from my answer?

Comment: At the top of the "Workload Identity" page it states: "This page explains the recommended way for your GKE applications to consume services provided by Google APIs" https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

Comment: On the other hand at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity you can find disclaimer `This product or feature is in a pre-release state and might change or have limited support.`. I'd recommend use non-beta features like this one https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall.

Comment: yeah, but do i go for stable now and depreciation later or beta now and stable later?

Comment: In case of any depreciation Google provides migration guide to ongoing stable technology. On the other hand, beta technology could change while it's moving to stable as you can see at the disclaimer and it has limited support.

Comment: Oh yeah, i've seen how Google handles depreciation on their projects i.e. Tensorflow: they make it hard to get to documentation and help. And then at some point you're faced with the pain of upgrading when the old version is fully depreciated. When starting new developments we also go for the latest versions/approaches as this maximises the time to the inevitable upgrade hell.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and managed to resolve it by changing the topicRef.name to topicRef.external with the fully qualified topic name as expected in the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/notifications/insert). My installation of the config connector was done following the Workload Identity scenario described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall).

```
---
apiVersion: storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: StorageNotification
metadata:
  name: storage-notification
spec:
  bucketRef:
    name: ${BUCKET}
  payloadFormat: JSON_API_V1
  topicRef:
    external: "//pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/topics/${TOPIC}"
  eventType:
    - "OBJECT_FINALIZE"
```

Comment: This works for me, I've tried the other answer and setting the `cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id` on all my resources and on my namespace using the following docs https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/setting-default-namespace#annotate_your_namespace_with_a_default_project_id

None of it worked, only this workaround did